# Are you allowed to Vape on a fast day?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, tobacco-cig-smoking

I was told that Vape has sugar in it. Are you inhailing enough for it to constitute a Shiur, and so not be able to Vape on a fast day?

Comment: Is eating less than a shiur permitted on fast days? I didn't know that

Comment: I've never heard of a shiur for inhaling sugar (or anything else). But I'm not very knowledgeable.

Comment: Are you allowed to any other day?

Comment: This sounds like an excellent question to pose to a knowledgeable LOR

Comment: The amount of sugar is obviously negligible

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Shmuel Chaim and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Are you allowed to vape at all? Stop killing youself

Comment: Theoretically inhaling doesn't count as eating or drinking, or the flavored snuffs which have been used on Yom Kippur for centuries would not have been permitted. But again, this is a question to pose to a LOR

Answer (score 1):

From Dinonline;

> Regular smoking is controversial and the Mishna Berura says not to smoke on Tisha B’av, except if the person is highely atticted to it, then he should only smoke after chatzos, and only in private. Smoking e-cigarettes is worse than smoking regular cigarettes because it also has a taste to it.

https://dinonline.org/2019/08/11/vaping-on-tishe-bov/

Comment: Might one reduce/remove the taste with "plain unflavoured" versions and approach the same status as regular cigarettes ?

Comment: Probably. The OP however was asking about the sugar, which indicates some kind of flavor